# Jquery Change color by input[type=text] keydown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to change the color of **Collapsible 1** when i keydown or key up on txt1,txt2 similarly for  **Collapsible 2**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
              Collapsible 1
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <section>
              <div class="section_inner">
                <input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" class="required"/>
                <input type="text" name="txt2" id="txt2" class="required"/>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
            Collapsible Group Item #2
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <section>
            <div class="section_inner">
              <input type="text" name="txt3" class="required"/>
              <input type="text" name="txt4" class="required"/>
              <input type="text" name="txt5" class="required"/>
              <input type="text" name="txt6"/>
            </div>
          </section>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

i have tried but its not working here is my code,how i can do this?

```
var collapseOne = 0;
//collapseOne reqeried validation
    $('#collapseOne input[type=text]').keyup(function(e){

        $('#collapseOne  input[type=text]').each(function(){

                if ( $(this).hasClass('required')  ){

                    if ( $(this).val() != ''  ){

                        collapseOne = 1;
                    }
                }
            });

            if ( collapseOne  == 1 ){
            $("h4").find("a").css("color","green");

            //$(this).find("data-id='collapseOne'").css("color","green");
            //$(this).closest('.panel-heading h4').css("color","green");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please put the code in fiddle and post the URL.

Comment: No element with class `required` and btw you are not targeting specific H4 but all

Comment: Try this `$('.panel-group input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){ if($(this).hasClass('required') && $(this).val() !== '') { $(this).closest('.panel').find('a').css({ color: 'green' }); } else { $(this).closest('.panel').find('a').css({ color: 'blue' }); } });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking:

```
if ( $(this).hasClass('required')  )
```

`$(this)` here refer to your input element with class `required`

However in yout HTML markup, you're not having any of your input with class `required`, try to add:

```
<input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1" class="required" />
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cvT2P/)**

---

If you want to target H4 according to the below input you can use:

```
$(this).closest('#collapseOne').siblings('.panel-heading').find('h4 a').css("color","green");
```

No need `if` condition here

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvT2P/1/)**

---

Ok, Here is the final solution:

```
var collapseOne = 0;

$('#collapseOne input[type=text]').keyup(function (e) {
    var h4Text = $(this).closest('#collapseOne').siblings('.panel-heading').find('h4 a');
    $('#collapseOne  input[type=text]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('required')) {

            if ($(this).val() != '') {

                collapseOne = 1;
            } else {
                collapseOne = 0;
            }
        }
    });

    if (collapseOne == 1) {
        h4Text.css("color", "green");
    } else {
        h4Text.css("color", "")
    }


});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvT2P/3/)**

Comment: i want to change only parent h4 tag

Comment: i have change color the code but its change the color of both h4,how i can do only parent?

Comment: basically i am willing to change the color when all field are filled,thats why i used collapseOne  == 1